# Cron job schedule parse error

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I'm trying to deploy my app with the following cron.xml file:

```
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/parse/</url>
    <description>test</description>
    <schedule>every 20 seconds</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

However, I keep getting an error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Deploying App to Google". Schedule every 20 seconds failed to parse
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One minute it the shortest period you can set. This is the [cron rule format](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#The_Schedule_Format):

```
every N (hours|mins|minutes) ["from" (time) "to" (time)]
```